# Elastic Query string not equal to

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, kibana-7

We have some requirement in kibana where we need to exclude some  request urls like ‘/ibe/document/*’ and fetch the other requests.

Options Tried

We have tried the below options

1. { "query": { "bool" : { "must_not" : { "term" : { "request.keyword" : "/ibe/document/.*" } } } } }
2. NOT ( "request.keyword" : "/ibe/document/.*")
3. !("request.keyword" : "/ibe/document/.*")

But even if we use any of the above queries,  In the filtered data, we are still getting records with  "request.keyword" : "/ibe/document/*”.
Can you provide suggestions on query to avoid this "request.keyword" : "/ibe/document/.*"

I have tried running all the above with  "request.keyword" : "/ibe/document/.*"  and "request.keyword" : "/ibe/document/*" . But every time,  the records corresponding to  requests "request.keyword" : "/ibe/document/*" are being fetched

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the below [wildcard query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-wildcard-query.html) to exclude all the results that start from `/ibe/document/`

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must_not": {
        "wildcard": {
          "request.keyword": "/ibe/document/*"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```